# How to add index next to a matrix

Tags: matrices

That is my actual matrix :[image]

And this is my code :

```
P_{i, j} = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & 0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 1 & \vdots & \vdots & (\text{ligne } i)\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 1 & 0 & 0 & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots & 0 & (\text{ligne } j) \\
        \vdots & \vdots & 0 & \vdots & 0 & \vdots & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
```

I would like the text to be next to the matrix, outside the brackets, but at the same height than now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the package `nicematrix`, you only have to change your environment `{pmatrix}` in `{pNiceMatrix}` and add the key `last-col`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$P_{i, j} = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col]
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & 0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 1 & \vdots & \vdots & (\text{ligne } i)\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 1 & 0 & 0 & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots & 0 & (\text{ligne } j) \\
        \vdots & \vdots & 0 & \vdots & 0 & \vdots & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

---

Here is another way to represent that matrix of transposition (also with `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle,code-for-first-col = \scriptstyle }
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}
\newcommand{\blue}{\color{blue}}
\[P_{i,j} = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-row,last-col,nullify-dots,xdots/line-style={dashed,blue}]
1& & & \Vdots & & & & \Vdots \\
& \Ddots[line-style=standard] \\
& & 1 \\
\Cdots[color=blue,line-style=dashed]&   &  & \blue 0 &
\Cdots & & & \blue 1 & & & \Cdots & \blue \leftarrow i \\
& & & & 1 \\
& & &\Vdots & & \Ddots[line-style=standard] & & \Vdots \\
& & & & & & 1 \\
\Cdots & & & \blue 1 & \Cdots & & \Cdots & \blue 0 & & & \Cdots & \blue \leftarrow j \\
& & & & & & & & 1 \\
& & & & & & & & & \Ddots[line-style=standard] \\
& & & \Vdots & & & & \Vdots & & & 1 \\
& & & \blue \overset{\uparrow}{i} & & & & \blue \overset{\uparrow}{j} \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes used by `nicematrix`).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I really enjoy each time you, @F. Pantigny, answer a question using nicematrix. +1.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Without any extra package, you have to add another adjacent matrix and make sure the vertical spacing in that matrix is the same as in the left one. It takes a little work. One way to do so is to use `\vphantom{}`, which doesn't typeset anything, doesn't take horizontal space at all, but still let LaTeX calculate occupied vertical space of its argument.

I would also base the solution on `array` instead of `bmatrix`, `pmatrx`, or `matrix`. It gives more control over alignments and spacing, still with possibility to add scaled brackets of any type.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\AtBeginDocument{\mleftright}
\setlength\arraycolsep{6pt}

\begin{document}

\[
P_{i, j} = 
    \left(                           % Auto-scaled open bracket
        \begin{array}{
                @{\hspace{6pt}}      % set space between left bracket and the first column
                *8{c}
                @{\hspace{6pt}}}     % as above but set space between the last column and the right bracket
            1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
            \vdots & 0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 1 & \vdots & \vdots \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 1 & 0 & 0 & \vdots & \vdots \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
            \vdots & \vdots & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
            \vdots & \vdots & 0 & \vdots & 0 & \vdots & 1 & 0 \\
            \vphantom{\vdots}
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
        \end{array}
    \right)                          % Auto-scaled closing bracket
    \hspace{1em}                     % space between two arrays
    \begin{array}{
            @{}                      % set no space between columns
            >{\vphantom{\vdots}}     % ensures the vertical spacing
            l
            @{}                      % - the same as above
            l
            @{}                      % - the same as above
        }
        \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{} & \\% cancels an effect of \vphantom{\vdots} in this row
        & \\
        & (\text{ligne } i)\\
        & \\
        & \\
        & (\text{ligne } j) \\
        & \\
        & \\
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This code is not the better one but it works without new package

```
$
P_{i, j} = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & 0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 1 & \vdots & \vdots &\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 1 & 0 & 0 & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots & 0 &  \\
        \vdots & \vdots & 0 & \vdots & 0 & \vdots & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{matrix}
        \vphantom{0}\\
        \vphantom{\vdots}\\
        \vphantom{\vdots}(\text{ligne } i)\\
        \vphantom{\vdots}\\
        \vphantom{\vdots}\\
        \vphantom{\vdots}(\text{ligne } j)\\
        \vphantom{\vdots}\\
        \vphantom{0}\\
        \end{matrix}
        $
```

Comment: I am not an expert, but please post your `MWE` from `\documentclass` ...`\end{document}` as always...